# Differentiation and endpoints of power series

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, sequences-and-series, power-series

It is known that the power series 
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$
and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  n a_n x^{n-1}$
have the same radius of convergence $r$. Is it true that
if $r<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  na_n r^{n-1}$ converges then
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty  a_n r^n$ converges, too? The same question for $-r$.
If not, what is a counterexample.

Comment: With an obvious change of variable, this amounts to the question without power series: if $\sum b_n$ converges, does $\sum b_n/n$ converge?

Comment: And it seems to be true, by Abel's summation formula. (Beware that we can have $\sum |b_n/n|=\infty$, e.g., when $b_n=(-1)^n/\log(n)$ where $\sum b_n$ converges.)

Comment: ... or use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).  You can replace $1/n$ by any sequence decreasing monotonically to $0$, and you don't even need $\sum b_n$ to converge, just that the partial sums are bounded.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand why this fact is true. 
By the way, can one see this fact with a proof somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Abel summation? it sounds hard not to find a proof...

Comment: Of course, it is easy to find a proof of Abel's summation and Dirichlet's test.
I asked about the application of these theorems to my question: is this fact
mentioned and explained somewhere in literature?